# I just had landscape curbing installed. On which side do I put a robotic mower boundary wire?

Tags: lawn-mower, hard-landscape

I'm considering purchasing a robot mower in the future. The [models I'm looking](https://www.husqvarna.com/us/robotic-lawn-mowers/) at use a [boundary wire](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/839726/Husqvarna-Automower.html?page=22).

I recently had landscape curbing installed. Should I put the boundary wire on the grass side of the curbing or the flowerbed side? The curbing is at ground-level. It's meant for a mower wheel to roll on it. The robotic mower can go on top of it easily.
[image: curbing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your linked manual, neither, unless the curbing is 12" wide. Either 12" from the flowerbed edge or 4" (both measured grasswards - into the lawn) from the grasswards edge of the curbing stone. It's fairly clear that the mower mows beyond the actual wire position from the linked instructions on where to locate it. The 4" recommendation is for things it's OK to mow over a bit. the 12" is to keep the wheels out of any low spot at the edge of the flowerbed.

As you have not bought the mower yet, likely best to wait until after you do and follow that specific model's instructions for wire placement, as how much they are likely to overhang the wire location probably varies by make and model.

Comment: Heh, I should have turned one page further in that manual I linked, shouldn't I? Oh, well. Thanks for answering! Now people like me can find their answer on SE.